# initialise a 4 channel matrix opencv

Tags: opencv

I am trying to initialise a 4 channel matrix with row = 1 and columns = 5, but I am always getting an exception `error: (-215) (unsigned)(i1 * DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1] * channels())` . Anyone knows what I am doing wrong.

```
            cv::Mat_<char> samples(1,5,CV_8UC4);

            samples.at<cv::Vec4b>(0,0) =  { 1,  2 , 3 , 4 } ;
            samples.at<cv::Vec4b>(0,1) =  { 1,  2 , 3 , 4 } ;
            samples.at<cv::Vec4b>(0,2) =  { 1,  2 , 3 , 4 } ;
            samples.at<cv::Vec4b>(0,3) =  { 1,  2 , 3 , 4 } ;
            samples.at<cv::Vec4b>(0,4) =  { 1,  2 , 3 , 4 } ;
```

Comment: I'm typically not using the template Mats, but did you mean: `cv::Mat_<cv::Vec4b> samples(1,5);` ? and then maybe: `samples.at<cv::Vec4b>(0,0) =  cv::Vec4b( 1,  2 , 3 , 4 });` ?

Comment: indeed ! such a silly with the init  ! The assignment is fine.

Comment: Probably better to use the typedef `cv::Mat4b`.